# How are C++20 modules compiled?

Tags: c++, c++-modules

Some sources say that compilers parse modules and create an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST), which is then used when parsing all code files that import the module. This would reduce the amount of parsing the compiler has to do as opposed to when #including headers, but everything would still have to be compiled once for every code file that imports a module.

Other sources say that modules are only compiled once.

How and when are modules compiled, and how does this affect inlining at compile time?

Comment: I suspect that depends on the compiler. The [Microsoft Visual C++ module docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) say `After a module is compiled once, the results are stored in a binary file that describes all the exported types, functions, and templates. The compiler can process that file much faster than a header file. And, the compiler can reuse it every place where the module is imported in a project` This doesn't say anything about linking or the actual executable code

Comment: "*Some sources say that compilers parse modules and create an abstract syntax tree (AST)*" Can you cite these sources that say that the results of a module build are an AST *and nothing more*?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't see why that last part is relevant? The question leaves open if the compiler perhaps also creates an additional hashtable for quick symbol lookup.

Comment: @MSalters: "*I don't see why that last part is relevant?*" Because the OP wouldn't have a question if they thought that modules contained more than just an AST. They wouldn't have thought that "everything would still have to be compiled once for every code file that imports a module".

Comment: @NicolBolas: That's not my interpretation. I read the question with code generation in mind - do compiled modules also include compiled function bodies? That made sense to me in the context of inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The products of module compilation are implementation dependent. But broadly speaking, they are whatever the compiler needs them to be to make module inclusion efficient. That is, after all, the whole point of modules. When building a module interface, the compiler has 100% of the information it needs to have to make including that module interface efficient.

Module compilation has only one special interaction with "inlining": member functions of a class defined within the class definition are *not* implicitly given an `inline` declaration. That's the only effect that modules have on "inlining".

And of course, the `inline` keyword is not strictly about "inlining". If you put definitions of things in a module's interface files, those definitions can be available for inlining by those who import those interfaces, whether the `inline` keyword is used (explicitly or implicitly) or not. This was true pre-modules, and it is still true in module builds.